# Get Table Name from using select

Tags: vb.net

```
            connection.Open()
            Dim adapter1 As New MySqlDataAdapter(TextBox1.Text, connection)
            Dim table As New DataTable()
            adapter1.Fill(table)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = table
```

I want to detect the table name that been selected from the query in textbox1.text 
exp

```
TextBox1.Text = "select * from Account_ID where entry = 123456"
```

So in this situation the table name is : Account_ID
But if it's something else how may i get the table name .. tried Split but still doesn't give a good result so may anyone know ?

Comment: what if its not a table name at all...but a nested query...also this method of free queries in an application opens you up to SQL injection risk...this is dangerous

Comment: Make a dropdownlist to select the table from? But be careful to validate the value before executing it on the server side, malicious user could post anything they want and drop the table or worse.

Comment: Well this has nothing to do with my database it's just an open table editor for something special so they put their own database information not mine and i explain how to use .. i means i just want to make the DataGridView also update(current)  / change / insert(new ) values like HeidiSQL use when you can see the columns and edit them so i will be using something similar to this :

Comment: Dim cmdbuilder As New Odbc.OdbcCommandBuilder(adp)
        Dim i As Integer
        Try
            i = adp.Update(ds, "trial1")
            MsgBox("Records Updated= " & i)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryed this and it works (if your connection string remains the same, I mean if you do not change the "*" SELECT with column enumeration SELECT):

```
    Dim words As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(New Char() {" "c})
    MessageBox.Show(words(3)) ''words(3) is Account_ID in your case
```

Hope it helps. ^^

Comment: Glad to hear that, have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I know that problem so well. I have know Idea will the DataTable-Object just dosen't get its name filled while using a DataAdapter.

So if I'm sure that there will only by simple queries used, I would use a regular expression to find the table name:

```
Dim TableName As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(TextBox1.Text, "(?<=from )\S+", Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
```

But if you need to bee really really sure you will need to find an SQL-Lexer and parse the code to find alle table names. Unfortunately I don't know any.

Maybe take a look at the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management` Namespace.